# Libreoffice Writer: how to enter data in a protected Word .doc form

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, forms, protected

I have a Word .doc file with form fields in it that I want to fill out in LibreOffice Writer.  The file is protected (in MS Word), so only the fields can have data entered into them.

However, none of the fields appear editable in Writer.  If I try to click on "Edit File" I get prompted to enter a password (which presumably was used to protect the document from general edits - that's **not** what I want to do).

How do I enable entering data into the designated fields of the document?

Comment: Is it possible to save a copy of the document (*Save as..*) that is not protected? This might be a work-around for that issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That works - I hadn't thought of trying that in *Writer*.  I did think ot trying *Save as...* from Word into a .odt, and that worked.  But I wanted a solution that **didn't** need Word.  Please post your suggestion as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save a copy of the document in LibreOffice Writer (*Save as..*) that is not protected as a possible work-around for that issue.